# Streams in Common Lisp?

Tags: stream, common-lisp

Section 3.5 of *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* describes streams.  Does Common Lisp have such streams built in or is there a good Common Lisp library implementing such streams?

[I mean streams in all the generality presented in section 3.5 of *SICP*; not just your usual i/o streams.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SERIES](http://series.sourceforge.net/) is a featureful library providing that sort of functionality.  For a shorter and more readable example of how the concept of streams maps to Common Lisp, see [Pipes](http://www.cliki.net/pipes).